# How to show and parse rsync progress in Python?

Tags: python, progress-bar, rsync

I am using the development version of `rsync` with `--info-progress` option. I am writing a python program which transfer files from server to local computer using rsync:

```
finalresult = subprocess.Popen(['sshpass', '-p', password, 'rsync', '-avz', '--info=progress2', 'hostname:/filename', '/home/nfs/django/user'],
                                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

When I run the program in the terminal, it doesn't show me the progress however if I use the rsync utility independently it shows the progress. I want to see the progress in the Terminal and parse or take the progress percentage to use it later to show progress bar to the user in real time. Thank you!

**Edit:**
This is what I have tried so far:
The code above stores the command processing in `finalresult` variable. I tried to print `finalresult` variable in the django template but it doesn't returns anything.

Comment: if you can work out a way to associate a callback with the (unbuffered) stdout then you're in business simply by reacting to chars as they come in.  Alternatively, be indirect, like monitor the file system and react to changes there - eg files growing, times changing? Just ideas.

Comment: I am trying to achieve the result using stdout. It would be great if someone point me out to the right direction.

Comment: Based from your established history of being a serial [help vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) I'm loathe to do it for you.  May I encourage your reformation into someone who is willing to better oneself by pointing you in [this direction](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).  When you've worked it out come back an post the answer.

Comment: I figured to show the progress bar in the terminal. How can I parse the progress and show in the real app?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20219/discussion-between-sachitad-and-john-mee)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but that probably cannot be done neither with `subprocess` nor with the rest of the standard library. And that is because inside `subprocess.communicate()` you would find:

```
def wait(self):
   """Wait for child process to terminate.  Returns returncode
   attribute."""
   if self.returncode is None:
      # Try calling a function os.waitpid(self.pid, 0)
      # Ignore Interrupted System Call (errno.EINTR) errors  
      pid, sts = _eintr_retry_call(os.waitpid, self.pid, 0)
      self._handle_exitstatus(sts)
   return self.returncode
```

On Unix the os.waitpid() function call means: Wait for completion of a child process given by process id pid, and return a tuple containing its process id and exit status indication. So, you have to wait until the child process is finished.

The closest alternative would be [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect), but it still won't do the progress bar analysis. A possible solution would be hacking rsync and patching its progress output so that pexpect could work with it.